# Change advertising iPhone local name

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

Using the CoreBluetooth framework is it possible to change the peripheral name of an iPhone that is advertising in peripheral mode?

For example:
I would like the peripheral iPhone to broadcast a custom name and have another iPhone be able to read the name upon central mode scan.

Is it possible to set the GAP name on a peripheral advertising iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must modify the Advertising Data when starting the Advertising. Add a Complete Local Name AD field.

```
[myPeripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:
    INSERT_NAME_HERE }];
```

Comment: This name will only be available if the advertising device is in the foreground. If it is in the background the local name key won't be advertised. I had to also create a readable characteristic in case the name isn't available.